# Как изменить цвет поля ввода текста в java?

Tags: java

есть окно, в нем два элемента - кнопка и текстовое поле(JTextField), как реализовать что бы после удаления символов из поля, оно становилось белым(до этого оно меняет цвет), это должно происходить автоматически при пустом поле

Answer (score 1):

Если нужно после выхода с поля менять цвет- вешаешь FocusListener и в методе focusLost проверяешь длину строки в поле:

```
JTextField field = new JTextField();
field.addFocusListener(new FocusListener() {
        @Override
        public void focusLost(FocusEvent e) {
             if (field.getText().isEmpty())
                 field.setBackground(new Color(255, 255, 255));
        }
});
```

Если текст будет менятся программно:

```
field.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener() {
    public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
        warn();
    }

    public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
        warn();
    }

    public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
        warn();
    }

    public void warn() {
        if (field.getText().isEmpty())
             field.setBackground(new Color(255, 255, 255));
    }
});
```

Comment: не пашет. надо - когда я жму на рядок и клавишей back space удаляю символы с поля, когда удалю последний символ он(рядок) должен стать белым. п.с. я работаю через jframe,